# Solution of $\tan x^3 = -\frac 32 x^3$?

Tags: calculus

How to solve $\tan x^3 = -\frac 32 x^3$? Could you give me advice?

Comment: Try sketching both graphs to get a feeling for what's going on.

Comment: A useful simplification is to note that $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, so that you may reduce to solving $\tan x = -\frac32 x$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, and how to solve the reduced equation? If there was no coefficient, it would be easy.

Comment: John, you say it's easy to solve $\tan x=-x$? or $\tan x=x$? I think you're mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given tan(x^3)=(-3/2)x^3

Implies : x^3=tan^-1((-3/2)*x^3)

x^3 is a curve that always lies the 1st quadrant and the 3rd quadrant, as the function returns a positive number for a positive input and a negative number for a negative input. Also note that, it passes through the origin.

tan^-1(x) also lies in the 1st and the 3rd quadrant, but tan^-1(-x) lies in the 2nd and the 4th quadrant, this curve also passes through the origin.

Therefore the only pt of intersection is at (0,0). Implies x=0, is the solution !

Comment: You have effectively restricted the domain of $\tan$ to $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ by using $\arctan$, which indeed cuts down on the number of solutions to a single one.

Comment: Oops yep, i'm sorry!